# Rails ujs and remote form, How to stop form submission the programmatically submit form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-ujs, form-with

I am using rails `form_with` as a remote form. Before submission I want to display a custom confirm box with a dynamic message. After the box is indeed confirmed I want to eventually submit the form.
I came up with 'ajax:beforeSend' event handler :

```
const form = document.getElementById('assign_sessions_to_employees')
form.addEventListener(
  'ajax:beforeSend',
  (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure ?',
      text: `You are about to spend ${expectedExpenditure()} credits.`,
      showCancelButton: true,
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        console.log('submitting')
        Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
      }
    })
  }
)
```

This works fine, however when I run `Rails.fire(form, 'submit');`, when I eventually want to submit the form this retriggers `'ajax:beforeSend'` and I get stuck in the loop.

What would be the correct way to achieve this behavior with form_with and rails ujs ?

Comment: Make the event handler a named function instead of an arrow function. That way you can [remove the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). Another technique is to just set a data attribute or add a class to the form element when the user confirms and put a guard statement at the top of the function which returns if it's present. https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/one-off-event-listeners-in-javascript-92e19c4c0336

Comment: @max Could you provide an example ? If I remove the listener in this case then I will no longer be able to show the confirm if a later form submit arises...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a function declaration (aka a named function) you can remove the event handler with [EventTarget.removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener):

```
function handleConfirmation(event){
  let form = event.target;
  event.preventDefault();
  swal.fire({
     title: 'Are you sure ?',
     text: `You are about to spend ${expectedExpenditure()} credits.`,
     showCancelButton: true,
  }).then((result) => {
     if (result.isConfirmed) {
       console.log('submitting');
       form.removeEventListener('ajax:beforeSend', handleConfirmation);
       Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
     }
    })
  }
}
const form = document.getElementById('assign_sessions_to_employees')
form.addEventListener('ajax:beforeSend', handleConfirmation);
```

Another alternative is to just set a data attribute in your event handler:

```
const form = document.getElementById('assign_sessions_to_employees')
form.addEventListener(
  'ajax:beforeSend',
  (event) => {
    if (event.target.dataset.confirmed) { return };
    event.preventDefault();
    swal.fire({
      title: 'Are you sure ?',
      text: `You are about to spend ${expectedExpenditure()} credits.`,
      showCancelButton: true,
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.isConfirmed) {
        console.log('submitting');
        form.dataset.confirmed = true;
        Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
      }
    })
  }
)
```